# Function as an argument

Tags: javascript

```
five = function(parameter1) {
  console.log(parameter1)
}

five(function() {
    var x = 5;
    return x;
})
```

I have passed an anonymous function as an argument to the five function, why is this function not logging 5?

Comment: try ```five = function(param1) { console.log(param1()) }```

Comment: You're not calling the function. `console.log(parameter1())`

Comment: Replace `console.log(parameter1);` with `console.log(parameter1());`.

Comment: Why do I need the () at the end of parameter1?

Answer (score 3):

```
five = function(parameter1) {
  console.log(parameter1())
}

five(function () {
    var x = 5;
    return x;
})
```

Change it like this, and it should work.

you did not call the function you just made a reference to it.

Comment: How could I have function where I have the parameter without the () and pass in variables or functions as arguments?

Answer (score 1):

```
five = function(parameter1) {
  console.log(parameter1()); // call the passed function
}

five(function() {
    var x = 5;
    return x;
})
```

Comment: How could I have function where I have the parameter without the () and pass in variables or functions as arguments?